# Is there anyway to turn `options` into a function same like `navigationOptions` do?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Currently, I was taking a course:**Multiplatform Mobile App Development with React Native** in coursera, and I was stuck at after every lecture because the instructor use `react-navigation@2.0.1` but I want to make sure to learn the latest version(v5). In this lecture he created a stack navigator and bring an icon to a screen like,

```js
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {
      screen: Menu,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            name="menu"
            size={24}
            color="white"
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        ),
      }),
    },
    Dishdetail: { screen: Dishdetail },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Menu'
  }
);
```

Where `navigationOptions` can be an object or be a function that takes in props.

I convert it like,

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator();
function MenuNavigatorScreen() {
  return (
    <MenuNavigator.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Menu"
      screenOptions={HeaderOptions}
    >
      <MenuNavigator.Screen
        name="Menu"
        component={Menu}
      />
      <MenuNavigator.Screen
        name="Dishdetail"
        component={Dishdetail}
        options={{ headerTitle: 'Dish Detail' }}
      />
    </MenuNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
```

But I was confused how to convert the `navigationOptions` functionality into my code. Because their [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#options) didn't tell how to trun my `options` object into a function to bring the `navigation` prop?

One more thing is he was using `drawerIcon`,

```js
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Login',
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon
            name="sign-in"
            type="font-awesome"
            size={24}
            color={tintColor}
          />
        ),
      }
...
```

But I didn't find anything related `drawerIcon` in Drawer navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation) 
I heartily thank if anyone helps me to figure out this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, The [options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#options) prop can be used to configure individual screens inside the navigator. And [headerLeft](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerleft) is a function that returns a React element to display on the left side of the header. When a function is used, it receives several arguments when rendered (onPress, label, labelStyle, and more - check [types.tsx](https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/blob/master/src/types.tsx) for the complete list).

```js
options = {
    ({
        navigation
    }) => ({
        headerLeft: () => ( <
            Icon name = 'menu'
            size = {
                24
            }
            color = 'white'
            onPress = {
                () =>
                navigation.toggleDrawer()
            }
            />
        )

    })
}
```

And for `drawerIcon` use:

```js
options = {
    {
        drawerIcon: ({
            tintColor
        }) => ( <
            Icon name = 'home'
            type = 'font-awesome'
            size = {
                24
            }
            color = {
                tintColor
            }
            />
        )
    }
}
```